# Python Unit test: Assertion Error issue

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am writing a unit test for the following function:

```
def _parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Script to configure appliance.'
    )
    parser.add_argument('--config_file',
                        help='Path to a JSON configuration file') 
    print parser.parse_args()
    return parser.parse_args()
```

When I run the function when no config file is given then (verified using the print statement in the function above):
`parser.parse_args()=Namespace(config_file=None)`

In my unit test I run the function with no config file given and include an assertEquals:

```
self.assertEquals(my_script._parse_args(), 'Namespace(config_file=None)')
```

But this produces the AssertionError:

```
AssertionError: Namespace(config_file=None) != 'Namespace(config_file=None)'
```

If I change the unit test to without the quotation marks:

```
self.assertEquals(my_script._parse_args(), Namespace(config_file=None))
```

I get a NameError:

```
NameError: global name 'Namespace' is not defined
```

Clearly using quotations is not the correct way to do this but how do I get it to assert that `Namespace(config_file=None)` is occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
self.assertEquals(my_script._parse_args(), Namespace(config_file=None))
```

to

```
self.assertEquals(my_script._parse_args(), argparse.Namespace(config_file=None))
```

`Namespace` is an attribute of the `argparse` module which you imported. You did not import `Namespace` on its own.

Demo for executing your code with no arguments:

```
print _parse_args() == argparse.Namespace(config_file=None) # True
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the `config_file` attribute of the returned `Namespace` object.

```
self.assertIsNone(my_script._parse_args().config_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function `_parse_args()` returns a Namespace object, not a string representation of it, that you get by calling `print parser.parse_args()`.

Let's look at your function:

```
def _parse_args():
    #some code
    print parser.parse_args()    <-- prints the string representation of the Namespace object 'Namespace(config_file=None)'
    return parser.parse_args()   <-- returns the Namespace object
```

For the object returned you can use the dot notation, to access attributes it's holding:

```
my_script._parse_args().config_file
```

and assert if it is not None:

```
self.assertIsNone(my_script._parse_args().config_file)
```

Or you can create any Namespace object by calling its constructor:

```
argparse.Namespace (config_file = None, another_arg='some value')
```

and use it in assertEqual:

```
self.assertEqual(my_script._parse_args(), argparse.Namespace (config_file = None))
```